# Missing symbol on libQt5Dbus.so.5?

Tags: qt, pyqt5

I have a python application that uses `QT5`.

I'm generating a binary for this app with `pyinstaller` (so that all the dependencies are bundled). This app is built from a `Centos6.8` docker instance (for compatibility reasons) with a patched-in `GLIBC` that `QT5` needs.

When I run the application it fails with the bundled `libQt5Dbus.so.5` not having the symbol `dbus_connection_can_send_type`:

```
symbol lookup error: /tmp/_MEIyxSbsB/libQt5DBus.so.5: undefined symbol: dbus_connection_can_send_type
```

When I do `nm -D /path/to/libQt5Dbus.so.5` on the `Centos6.8` docker instance doesn't show the symbol I need (`dbus_connection_can_send_type`).

What can I do to get the symbol in a `libQt5Dbus.so.5`?

EDIT:
I have found that one of the `libQt5Dbus.so.5` library in my system does actually have `dbus_connection_can_send_type` symbol. I've replaced all `libQt5Dbus.so.5` libraries with the one that does have the symbol and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I had was the minimum `GLIBC` required by QT5 (`GLIBC 14`) does not define the symbol `dbus_connection_can_send_type` (among others).

Upgrading it to `GLIBC 17` makes it work again.